# How to find volume of this solid?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, 3d, volume

The task is to find volume of a solid given by this system of inequalities:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^8 + \left(\frac{|y|}{5}\right)^5  < 1 ,\\
\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^8 + \left(\frac{|z|}{3}\right)^{40/27} < 1 .
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
I tried this:
$$V = \iiint \,dx\,dy\,dz$$ 
$$ 4u = x, 5v = y, 3w = z$$
So, 
$$
\begin{split}
V &= 60\iiint \,du\,dv\,dw \\
  &= 60 \int_{-1}^{1}du
        \int_{-(1-u^8)^{1/5}}^{(1-u^8)^{1/5}} dv
        \int_{-(1-u^8)^{27/40}}^{(1-u^8)^{27/40}} dw \\
  &= 240 \int_{-1}^{1}(1-u^8)^{7/8}du 
\end{split}
$$

And I got stuck here. Is my solution right and, if so, how can I solve the last integral? And if this solution is wrong, how can I solve this problem in other way?

Comment: I don't think there is an analytic form for the antiderivative, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%281-u%5E8%29%5E%287%2F8%29%2C+%7Bu%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D) has it through some special function. However, the definite integral does converge to $$\frac{7\pi}{32} \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)$$ although as of right now, I am not sure how to get there. An Interesting substitution to try is $u = \csc t$ and see where the trig simplification takes you.